# Transparent model does not render correctly, looks ok while editing texture

Tags: rendering, texturing, eevee-render-engine, transparency

I have imported a model of this tree and I am attempting to include it within a scene. The area surrounding the leaves shows up as transparent in the texture editor (first picture), but does not render properly (second picture). I'm using png and RGBA for output, so I'm not sure why it won't show up properly.

Any tips on fixing this?

Edit: Added file. Model is not mine. [image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Properties window, go to the Material Properties tab. Scroll down to Settings and change the Blend Mode form Opaque to Alpha Blend (or possibly Alphas Clip or Alpha Hashed, depending on your preference).

It is the same for EEVEE and Cycles.
However, take care not to confuse the aforementioned Settings with the Settings under Viewport Display that are available in Cycles, since they only affect the 3D Viewport and not the render.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have attempted all of those but it still gives me the same output, I'm not sure why...

Comment: That's to bad. If you are willing to share a blender file though, I'd be happy to have a look and see if i can come up with something else. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Not my model, but this is the file I'm working on. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=zvPOx6vS" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/zvPOx6vS/)

Comment: Added it in the original question in case it doesn't work in the comment.

Comment: Ah, but this file is missing the texture. You can add it by going to File (in to top left corner) > Eternal Data, and check the box next to "Automaticly Pack into .Blend" and then save the file again.

Comment: That did not work for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more clear. I was asking you to upload the file again with the texture packed into it, so i can also see it. (now the model has no texture when I look at it)